# C#-The database cannot be opened because it is version 706

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to connect but get error

> The database cannot be opened because it is version 706. This server supports version 655 and earlier. A downgrade path is not supported

My SQL Version :

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.2100.60 (X64) 
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)
```

My connection string :

```
"Server=.\\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=" + datasource + ";Trusted_Connection=Yes;User Instance=True;"
```

Why is it not connecting? I transferred from x86 to x64 system and installed same software which were on x86.The software I installed are x64 based.

Comment: Are you _absolutely sure_ ".\\SQLExpress" refers to the SQL Server 2012 Express instance you mention as "my specs"? It sounds like you might have a leftover 2008 instance sitting around that you're inadvertently trying to attach your database to.

Comment: if so how do i change it to 2012 instance

Comment: Try to connect to `.\SQLExpress` with Mgmt Studio and run `SELECT @@Version` - what do you get? If that's a 2008 version (which I assume it is), then your SQL Server **2012** Express must be installed under a different instance name. Find out what that is, connect to that instance - and you're done!

Comment: FYI my specs = my version

Answer (score 4):

You **CANNOT** do this - you cannot attach/detach or backup/restore a database from a **newer version** of SQL Server (with an internal database version of 706 - probably SQL Server 2012) down to an **older version** (your engine supports versions up to 655 - that's SQL Server 2008) - the internal file structures are just too different to support backwards compatibility.

You can either get around this problem by

- using the same version of SQL Server on all your machines - then you can easily backup/restore databases between instances
- otherwise you can create the database scripts for both structure (tables, view, stored procedures etc.) and for contents (the actual data contained in the tables) either in SQL Server Management Studio (`Tasks > Generate Scripts`) or using a third-party tool
- or you can use a third-party tool like Red-Gate's [SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/) and [SQL Data Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/) to do "diffing" between your source and target, generate update scripts from those differences, and then execute those scripts on the target platform; this works across different SQL Server versions.